# Apache returning text/html on some png files

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mime

I have an Apache web server that has a sub folder for images. 
For some reason, a few of the .png files are returned as text/html and not as image/png.

There is nothing indicating a permission problem and the files return with code 200 and with full size. 
I made sure that image/png is set and even tried forcing it with .htaccess

Any idea where to look next?

Edit: looks like an .htaccess configuration problem on a parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure png files are valid image files? If you are on a Linux platform you can try the file command

```
file somefile.png
```

That command should return something along the lines of

```
PNG image data, 318 x 15, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

You can also try to view the file with a image viewer.

Comment: logo.png: PNG image data, 256 x 256, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
the same file opens on all windows machines i have.
i also made sure it wasnt broken in scp / wget

Comment: Did you try different web browsers? Maybe there is a problem with the one you are using? Could you post a link for us to test?

Comment: Sorry, cant put a link, but i tried other browsers on other hosts.
Looking at the http response i can tell its not a client side problem.

Comment: Are you using compression options of Apache? This page http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html indicates a configuration inorder not to compress image files.[page]:

Comment: ok, i found the cause. changing the file name did the trick (not every file name i choose work). it must be something in one of the parent directory's .htaccess files

Thanks for the help

Comment: interesting : ) glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that the image file to be delivered was named `pear.php.net-sos8j3lis2j.png`.

[Apache's `AddHandler` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#AddHandler) - that's used to assign the PHP interpreter to .php files 
- supports [multiple extensions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext), and `pear.php.net.png` was seen as having three extensions: `.php`, `.net` and `.png`. `.php` was the first, to the php interpreter was invoked.

`text/html` was then sent out by either apache or PHP, I don't know.

---

What I had to do to fix the problem:

Replace all instances of

```
AddHandler php-cgi .php
```

with

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler php-cgi
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look for .png, .PNG, .pNG and .PNg.